# Who were parents of Nettie A Priddy born 1867 in Tennessee, USA?

Tags: united-states, birth-records, tennessee

I am looking for the parents of Nettie A Priddy, born 4 July 1867 in Tennessee, United States and died 17 May 1891 in Wichita Falls, Wichita, Texas, United States.

She was married to James Edwin Gilbreath.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  If you have any additional information that might help us to try and identify your ancestor there is an edit button beneath your question which will let you update it at any time.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us what searches you have already tried, so we can avoid telling you to do stuff you've already done.

Comment: A death at 24 sounds like something that would be recorded in local newspapers.  Would you be able to use the edit button beneath your question to mention whether or not you have tried using that possible source, please?

Answer (score 3):

Marriage index Cooke County, Texas, lists her as A. N. Priddy. Tombstone says A. N. Gilbreath. Could Nettie be short for Annette, Antoinette, or Anita?

Marriage of son James says mother was Nettie Pretty born in Brandon, Texas.

Death Certificate of son Thomas says mother was Preddy born in Texas.

Death certificate of son George says mother was Alice Priddy born in Texas. (George's step-mother was Alice Wells)

I find no Priddy's in Cooke County, Texas in 1880. 1900 census shows one family - Charles P. Priddy born 1869 in Tennessee. Traced him back and none of his sisters fit with Nettie.

I would suggest you find the marriage license. If she married at age 16, her father should have given permission. Also should check for any Priddy's in city directories 1880 thru 1900 in Cooke county. Contact the Cooke County Library at http://cookecountylibrary.org/research/  and have them look for her obituary at the Wichita Falls Library http://www.wfpl.net/research/databases

Also check with this guy to see if there are any cemetery records available - http://www.cemeteries-of-tx.com/Wtx/Wichita/cemetery/Riverside.html